# Some icons in Gnome applications are very large

Tags: xubuntu, icons, 15.04

I currently have both Unity and Xubuntu/Xfce installed. Recently, I upgraded to 15.04. One problem that I came across was that certain icons in GNOME applications (or at least I think it's only GNOME applications) are very oversized.

Here are some screenshots: [http://imgur.com/a/haHvi](https://imgur.com/a/haHvi)

Also, you may have noticed that my background changed had changed in the screenshot of Nautilus. For some reason, opening Nautilus automatically changes my background to the one I use in Unity. No other program does this.

I am using the Square Icon Pack which can be found [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/03/square-icon-theme-is-now-available-in.html). If I switch to another icon pack, the problem goes away and the icons return to their proper sizes.

Why would this be happening? Is the icon pack I'm using "not ready" for 15.04 or something? Does having Xfce installed on top of Unity cause the wallpaper to be switched when Nautilus is opened? Is there any way I could avoid these issues?

Thanks in advance,
idtownie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The problem was, in the icon theme's index.theme file, all of the scalable icons were set to have a minimum size of 257 px. Therefore, that was the smallest they could get. If you are experiencing this problem and want to fix it, this is where you would change the minimum size:

```
[scalable/emblems]
Size=331
Context=Emblems
Type=Scalable
MinSize=257
MaxSize=512

[scalable/mimetypes]
Size=331
Context=MimeTypes
Type=Scalable
MinSize=257
MaxSize=512

[scalable/places]
Size=331
Context=Places
Type=Scalable
MinSize=257
MaxSize=512

[scalable/status]
Size=331
Context=Status
Type=Scalable
MinSize=257
MaxSize=512
```

Simply change all the `MinSize` lines that are under a `scalable` entry to equal 8. Save and reload your icon theme and you're good to go!